# Interpreting result of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, notation, word-problem

I'm having trouble interpreting the results of matrix multiplication.  For example,

> Matrix $A$ gives the **time** that is required for two different $B$akeries to make a donut and a scone.
> $A= 
> \begin{array}{c c} 
> & \begin{array}{c c } B_1 & B_2 \\ \end{array} \\
> \begin{array}{c c }Donuts\\Scones\\ \end{array} &
> \left[\begin{array}{c c }
> 5 & 6 \\
> 10 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \end{array}$
>
> So my row labels are donuts and scones and my column labels are $B_1$ and $B_2$.  I'll call these *snacks*.

> Matrix $B$ give the **orders** from two different $C$ustomers for donuts and scones.
> $B= 
> \begin{array}{c c} 
> & \begin{array}{c c } Donuts & Scones \\ \end{array} \\
> \begin{array}{c c }Customer_1\\Customer_2\\ \end{array} &
> \left[\begin{array}{c c }
> 5 \quad & 6 \\
> 10 \quad & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \end{array}$
>
> So my row labels are $Customer_1$ and $Customer_2$ and my column labels are Donuts and Scones.

If I multiply $A$ and $B$, I get

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 700 & 540 \\ 1100 & 920 \end{bmatrix}$

What do these quantities represent?  Since I multiplied row of $A$ against columns of $B$, I assume the resulting quantities represent $A_{rows}B_{columns}$ of "stuff". So it seems that I have $700$ "snacks-bakery-time" (from $A$) of "snacks-customer-orders" (from $B$).  This doesn't seem to make much sense, but matrix multiplication does not always make sense.

If instead, I had multiplied $B$ times $A$, I would have gotten $B_{rows}A_{columns}$ of "stuff".  That multiplication results in this matrix:

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 850 & 780 \\ 775 & 770 \end{bmatrix}$

So, in this case, $850$ is "customer-snacks-order--bakery-snacks-time".  Put another way, it means that $Customer_1$'s donut order can be produced by $B_1$ in $850$ minutes.

Am I correct?

Are the quantities in matrix multiplication $\boxed{M_1\text{-row-column-unit--}M_2\text{-column-row-unit}}$**?**
*(In Given Example, the "units" are orders and time respectively.)*

Comment: Hint: For AB to make sense, if rows of A denote time, then column of B should denote rate (i.e., 1/t) of some quantity "q", so that their product denotes "q". 
If AB makes sense, then BA need not always make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the numbers of customers, snacks and bakeries to be the same.  You can multiply $AB$ if the number of columns of $A$ is the same as the number of rows of $B$.

Your matrix product $AB$ would make sense if the **columns** of $A$ and the **rows** of $B$ were labelled by the snacks, which seems to be the reverse of what you have.  Then if the entry of $A$ in row $i$, column $j$ is the time for bakery $i$ to bake one item of snack $j$, and the entry of $B$ in row $j$, column $k$ is the number of snack $j$ ordered by customer $k$, their product is the time for bakery $i$ to bake the snack $j$'s ordered by customer $k$.  Add that up over all snacks $j$ and you find that the 
entry of $AB$ in row $i$, column $k$ is the total time needed for bakery $i$ to fill
customer $k$'s order.